# Some asymptotics of soliton solution

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics, soliton-theory

Let $\xi=x-16 t$ and consider
$$
u(x,t)=-12\frac{3+4\cosh(2\xi+24t)+\cosh(4\xi)}{\left(3\cosh(\xi-12t)+\cosh(3\xi+12t)\right)^2}
$$

Now fix $\xi$; it is said that

It is said that
$$
u(x,t)\sim -8\operatorname{sech}^2(2\xi-\frac{1}{2}\log 3)\textrm{ as }t\to\infty.~\tag{*}
$$

(1) How can $\xi$ be fixed if $\xi=x-16 t$ and $t\to\infty$?

(2) How to see $(*)$?

As to (2), I already used $\cosh(x)=\frac{1}{2}(e^x+e^{-x})$ to write
$$
u(x,t)=-12\frac{3+2\left(e^{2\xi+24t}+e^{-2\xi-24t}\right)+\frac{1}{2}\left(e^{4\xi}+e^{-4\xi}\right)}{\frac{1}{4}\left\{9\left(e^{2\xi-24t}+2+e^{-2\xi+24t}\right)+e^{6\xi+24t}+2+e^{-6\xi-24t}+6\left(e^{4\xi}\color{red}{+e^{-2\xi-24t}+e^{2\xi+24t}}+e^{-4\xi}\right)\right\}}
$$

Does this help? I don't know how to continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To (1): Saying that $\xi$ is fixed while $\xi=x-16$ should be read as $x=x(t)=\xi+16t$ for that value of $\xi\in\mathbb{R}$, so $x$ is an implicit function.

To (2): If you factor out $e^{24t}$ both in the numerator and denominater and let them cancel out, the remaining terms do all vanish but $(-24)e^{2\xi}$ in the numerator and $\frac{9}{4}e^{-2\xi}+\frac{1}{4}e^{6\xi}$ in the denominator. That would be the leading term of the asymptotics. Now one has to show that this and $(*)$ coincide.

Comment: I forgot the terms which are now marked in red in the original post. With these additional terms, I get, asymptotically as $t\to +\infty$, $$u(x,t)\sim\frac{-24 e^{2\xi}}{\frac{9}{4}e^{-2\xi}+\frac{1}{4}e^{6\xi}+\frac{3}{2}e^{2\xi}}=-\frac{24}{\frac{1}{4}\left(9e^{-4\xi}+e^{4\xi}+6\right)}=-\frac{96}{e^{4\xi}+6+9e^{-4\xi}}$$. And if I am not mistaken, this coincides with $$ -8\operatorname{sech}^2(2\xi-\frac{1}{2}\log 3)=-\frac{32}{e^{-\log 3+4\xi}+2+e^{\log 3-4\xi}}=-\frac{-32}{\frac{1}{3}\left(e^{4\xi}+6+9e^{-4\xi}\right)}=-\frac{96}{e^{4\xi}+6+9e^{-4\xi}}$$

Comment: Looks good on first glance. Does that answer your question?